# Springboot : Failed to evaluate expression 'hasRole('USER') and #userId == principal.userId'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I implemented a UserPrincipalManager class that implements UserDetails. I added a field containing a generated string that I use as Id that is passed as path params.

```
public class UserPrincipalManager implements UserDetails {    
    private final UserModel userModel;

    @Getter @Setter
    private String userId;

    @Autowired
    public UserPrincipalManager(UserModel userModel) {
        this.userModel = userModel;
        this.userId = userModel.getUserKeyId();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        Collection<AuthorityModel> authorityModelEntities = new HashSet<>();
        // get user roles
        Collection<RoleModel> roleModels = userModel.getRoles();
        if (roleModels == null) {
            return authorities; // null
        }
        // get user roles
        roleModels.forEach((role) ->{
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
            authorityModelEntities.addAll(role.getAuthorities());
        });
        // get user authorities
        authorityModelEntities.forEach(authorityModel -> {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authorityModel.getName()));
        });

        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.userModel.getEncryptedPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.userModel.getEmail();
    }

    // we do not store this information in DB
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    // we do not store this information in DB (yet)
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    // we do not store this information in DB (yet)
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    // isEnabled depending if account is activated => email verification status value
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.userModel.getEmailVerificationStatus();
    }
}
```

In my controller, I want to allow entry point only to administrators and registered users. In my @PreAuthorized I have the following SPEL:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') or #userId == principal.userId")
@GetMapping(
        path = "/users/{userId}/projects",
        produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE }
)
public Set<ProjectResponseModel> getUserProjects(@PathVariable(value = "userId") String userId) {
    log.info("# getProfiles() called");

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

    Set<ProjectResponseModel> returnValue;
    Set<ProjectDto> projectDtos = projectService.getUserProjects(userId);
    returnValue = modelMapper.map(projectDtos, new TypeToken<Set<ProjectDto>>(){}.getType());

    return returnValue;
}
```

For #id i can see the value is correctly mapped. I do obtain a string value.

My Security config contains the following configure method:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtTokenProvider))
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity()
            .maxAgeInSeconds(0)
            .includeSubDomains(true);
}
```

And of course I added the following annotation:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
```

In my filter:

```
public class AuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    public AuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                               JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        super(authenticationManager);
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(SecurityConstants.OPTIONS_HTTP_METHOD)) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        } else {
            String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
            if(authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }
            String token = authorizationHeader.substring(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX.length());
            String userName = jwtTokenProvider.getSubject(token);
            if(jwtTokenProvider.isTokenValid(userName, token) && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthorities(token);
                Authentication authentication = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(userName, authorities, request);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            } else {
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, I do obtain an error message:

```
2021-03-15 16:38:43.870 DEBUG 17920 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'hasRole('USER') and #userId == principal.userId']
2021-03-15 16:38:43.872 DEBUG 17920 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
2021-03-15 16:38:43.876 DEBUG 17920 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2021-03-15 16:38:43.876 DEBUG 17920 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I don't really know what's wrong.

Comment: What is userId? Is this the username?

Comment: userId is a random string of letters ... I define it in UserPrincipalManager which implements UserDetails

Comment: why are you using a custom JWT filter when spring security already has a JWT filter, and full JWT support?

Comment: So you have a custom Principal that must be casted to access userid.

Comment: i also tried to access directly my UserPrincipal : #userId == userPrincipalManager.getUserModel.userKeyId"

Comment: That's interesting that your logs tell you that the evaluation failed, but not why. Are you able to increase log levels to get a more detailed explanation?

Comment: i have no more details ... i set log level to trace ...

Comment: @davidvera BTW: Is that a typo? `hasRole('ADMIN') or #userId == principal.userId"` instead of `hasRole('USER') and #userId == principal.userId'` Or do you have another constraint somewhere else?

Comment: @davidvera Add a breakpoint at `Authentication authentication = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(userName, authorities, request);` and check if the authentication really has a principal of type `UserPrincipalManager `.

Comment: I did this. I was getting a string. I replaced it with an instance of UserPrincipalManager and I still have the same issue